# Hide style props in VScode extention

Tags: reactjs, vscode-extensions, chakra-ui

I am looking for an extension, maybe their is a setting?, that would hide the big style block in my React components. I am using Chakra UI Library and all styles are given using properties so a single div may look like this:

```
    <Box
      display="flex"
      flexDirection="column"
      margin="0 auto"
      maxWidth="330px"
      paddingTop="32px"
    >
```

And potentially even larger! And this gets annoying real quick as the more components you use, the larger and larger the file gets so more and more scrolling is required to get from the top of the file to the bottom. Even using just 6 components - its 97 lines of codes like this! Thats insane!

I wonder if their is an extension that would compress the properties to like `<Box ...>` and once the cursor is on the line then it would expand (similar to tailwind extension).

I tried searching for such extension but sadly found nothing.

Comment: Why not consider using plain CSS or even better, SASS? Would make your life a lot easier. You could simple write a simple class and attach it to your components through `className`.

Comment: Or alternatively, use a different UI library...

Comment: @MikeLischke I would. But, Im not the only one on this project and I did not make the rules of what we can and cant use. So sadly its not up to me to change such things.

Comment: @derFrosty ^ I would but I cant. Project rules are set do use these

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you will find a plugin for this. You could go with a structure like this.

Create a file called `BoxStyles.js` inside:

```
export default {
  display: "flex"
  flexDirection: "column"
  margin: "0 auto"
  maxWidth: "330px"
  paddingTop: "32px"
}
```

Then in the file where you are using the `Box` component.

```
import BoxStyles from './BoxStyles';

<Box {...BoxStyles} />
```

This will help keep file sizes smaller.

Hope that helps

Comment: sadly it dosent. Could just simply use sass, or css, at this point as this approach does basically same thing. But also creates loads of js files. Sadly the project rules are set to not do this nor any sass/css unless required (not possible via lib). But thx for your effort

Answer (score 0):

You could use this extension I wrote to do this: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).  You can make use of its ability to find regex matches and then run a command on them.

The command `editor.createFoldingRangeFromSelection` lets you create a folding range for anything you can select.

So try this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`) :

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+i",            // whatever binding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(?<=<Box)[\\s\\n\\S]*?>",
    "isRegex": true,
    "matchCase": true,
    "postCommands": [
      "editor.createFoldingRangeFromSelection"
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && editorLangId == javascriptreact"
}
```

[image: folding javascript props]

You can remove all the manually-created folding ranges (those created with a selection and the command) with the command: `Remove Manual Folding Ranges`.

Comment: hmh this is not 100% what I wanted but its close and might do the trick. Will try it out, thx

Comment: hmh.. @Mark sadly it does not do it... All it does is mark all of the properties of `Box` but it does not fold it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Oh come on!!

ofcourse, there should be an extension / plugin

Ofcourse it is a pain in the ass...

for tailwind try: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stivo.tailwind-fold

Im looking one for MUI, so please share!

Comment: im not using tailwind. as the post say, im using Chakra UI. and sadly, it does not work with it :( but thx for the extention link - will use it in projects that use tailwind